# How do i add toggle button that mute/unmute all in app sound

Tags: android, audio, toggle, mute

How do i add toggle button that mute/unmute all in app sound preferably a video on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private boolean _myAudioToggle;
    onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // ...
        _myAudioToggle = false; // audio is off, set to true to default to on
        setAudio(_myAudioToggle);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourButton); // where yourButton is in your layout XML file
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener {

            @Override
            onClick(View v) {
                _myAudioToggle = !_myAudioToggle;
                setAudio(_myAudioToggle);
            }
        });
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Create a method called setAudio() that takes a boolean value and sets the audio :)

```
private void setAudio(boolean audioToggle) {
    // your code to toggle the audio
}
```

Comment: No.  Sorry.  I can help you along with code, but I don't have time to train you :)